# How do I store HashMaps in mongodb using morphia?

Tags: mongodb, persistence, hashmap, morphia

How do i store HashMaps in mongodb using morphia?

I'm not sure if this is a bug in morphia, or if i'm just doing it wrong.

say i have this domain model

```
@Entity("person")
public class Person {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    private HashMap<String, Thing> things;
}
```

when i try to save this using a class that extends BasicDAO repo.save(personInstance) i get this error: (UsedView is the equivalent of Thing in the example above)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.model.designed.UsedView
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:205)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putMap(BSONEncoder.java:245)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:177)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:121)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:189)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:245)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:209)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:622)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:731)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:793)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:787)
    at com.google.code.morphia.dao.BasicDAO.save(BasicDAO.java:109)...

Then if i changed:

```
"private HashMap<String, Thing> things"
```

to

```
"private HashMap<String, String> things"
```

it saves it fine.

any thoughts?

much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

old question I realize, but I came across this: (untested)

"...This could contain any basic types supported by the MongoDB driver including Lists and Maps, but no complex objects unless you have registered converters with Morphia (e.g. `morphia.getMapper().getConverters().addConverter(new MyCustomTypeConverter())`."

From: 
http://www.carfey.com/blog/using-mongodb-with-morphia/

As said: untested.

hth.

Comment: interesting, i'll give this a try soon. i'm a bit loaded with work right now. i'll report back soon. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Is `Thing` mapped as a Morphia entity?  If not, morphia won't know how to save it to mongo.

Comment: humm, no it's not. usually if i define in the class Thing thing; it gets persisted correctly. i'll give your suggestion a try today and see what happens.

Comment: so i finally had the time to try what you suggested, but no dice. thanks though